# What are the default Eclipse update sites?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I just installed and opened Eclipse for the first time on my new laptop and the plugin installer has no available update sites. How can I fix this, or what are the default update sites?

Comment: See also https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=249133 for a case where the update manager is blank.

Comment: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Project_Update_Sites

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have a [full list here](http://ekkescorner.wordpress.com/eclipse/update-sites/) (thanks to [ekke](http://ekkescorner.wordpress.com/about/)).

> Galileo:

- Releases: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo (should be automatically installed)
- Maintenance builds: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.5 (should be automatically installed)
- Milestones: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.5milestones
- EPP Packages http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/galileo/

Note: With Helios (3.6Mx), you would have at least:

- Releases (Helios): http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios
- Updates: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.6

With Juno (current 4.2):

- Releases: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/
- Updates: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.2

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why, but the download did not include any of the download sources.

Answer (score 2):

For 3.7 (Indigo) on Ubuntu, there were no default sites. So I downloaded the portable one and exported the update sites. You can just save this and import it in 3.7.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookmarks>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo" selected="true" name="Indigo"/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.7" selected="true" name="The Eclipse Project Updates"/>
</bookmarks>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's something along these lines, although I can't seem to find it now, and don't have Eclipse installed here.  There might be a path extension on it for different versions.

http://update.eclipse.org/

Answer (score 0):

Just an update for this issue which I have hit yesterday too. This has been fixed since 4.3M4, see [this comment](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=249133#c48) on the respective issue.